# Overflow: hidden;

Tags: css

Задумка в том, что автомобиль виден только внутри блока .invis. Но overflow:hidden не дает результата.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #94C0EA;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.invis {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.train {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.train::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: -8px;
  left: 10px;
}

.wheel1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

.wheel2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

.backlight {
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.frontlight {
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ground {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #3D2D2B;
}

.triangle1,
.triangle2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invis">
    <div class="train">
      <div class="wheel1">
        <div class="triangle1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wheel2">
        <div class="triangle2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="backlight"></div>
      <div class="frontlight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ground"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно поставить блоку `.invis` свойство `postition: relative;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #94C0EA;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.invis {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.train {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.train::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: -8px;
  left: 10px;
}

.wheel1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

.wheel2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

.backlight {
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.frontlight {
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ground {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #3D2D2B;
}

.triangle1,
.triangle2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invis">
    <div class="train">
      <div class="wheel1">
        <div class="triangle1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wheel2">
        <div class="triangle2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="backlight"></div>
      <div class="frontlight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ground"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не знал, что position отвечает еще и за такие моменты...